# Do getResourceAsStream and FileInputStream have the same performance?

Tags: java, performance, fileinputstream

I have to implement some performance tests on an application. This application can load files from both classpath (using `getResourceAsStream`) and file system (using a `FileInputStream`).

I was wondering if I have to take this into account and duplicate the tests to cover both cases or if they are somewhat equivalent (considering multiple consecutive calls).

So, is one method faster than the other?

Thanks.

Comment: likely the same, except if you load from inside a jar file - this would require extra unzip operation. But I doubt this is noticeable. What is important here is buffering your operations (use a BufferedReader/BufferedInputStream), as this is what will makes the difference between fast and slow as hell.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Java 9+ made a few changes to `getResourceAsStream` to take advantage of the module system.

Comment: @JacobG. at the moment I'm using Java 8 but I don't think there's any problem with changing the Java version. I've just looked up the Java 9 release notes but I didn't quite get if this affects performances. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks

Comment: @spi you made me notice that I actually forgot to make the streams buffered... also, I'm loading from jars so your comment is really helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Aurasphere most likely you don't need to bufferize anything when using ``getResourceAsStream``, as it (seems) done by the class ``sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection``: the type of InputStream returned is a ``ByteArrayInputStream``. The same note does not apply if you use a ``FileInputStream``.

Comment: @spi ok, thanks again, very helpful informations!